# Select Multiple Button and Save value for each button in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I'm trying to make choice option using discord.ui.button and a callback function but when I choose a button the pervious choose reset the value and show me my new choose but I want to show previous choose two.

I tried to make my variable value Global but Nothing changed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I will answer your question, but next time try to show the code you have tried, the possible issue, etc. It makes life easier for the rest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the ui Widgets that have been interacted with, with `self.edited`. Once all are True, then all have been modified and you can do the rest of your code. (In my case it's Select menus, but you can edit to apply with buttons.)

```py
class multiple_widgets(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        self.edited = [False, False] #One for each widget

        super().__init__()


    async def global_callback(self, interaction):
        if not all(self.edited) or not self.children[0].values or not self.children[1].values: #Check if all are edited (and have values, optional, in case someone empties it back again
            return await interaction.response.defer()
        else:
            self.edited = [False, False]
            #Here do wathever you would normally do

    @discord.ui.select()
    async def select_callback_1(self, interaction, item):
        self.edited[0] = True
        await self.global_callback(interaction)
        #You can also do code for specific button here

    @discord.ui.select()
    async def select_callback_2(self, interaction, item):
        self.edited[1] = True
        await self.global_callback(interaction)
        #You can also do code for specific button here
```